# Extend or remove Data Explorer timeout

Tags: feature-request, bug, data-explorer, logout

I know that we don't have automatic login for the Data Explorer, but what's with the automatic timeout/logout?  There have been times that I am logged into the site, maybe I walk away for a little bit, and I come back to being logged out.

Is there a reason for logging us out of Data Explorer?  If so, is it possible to either remove the timeout or extend the period of time before timeout?

Answer (score 21):

This actually isn't a feature, it's an issue with how the site is configured when it's deployed that causes your session to be unintentionally invalidated when the application cycles (or [so I was told](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/495?m=1233312#1233312)).

I'll see if I can convince Nick to make the necessary tweaks to the deployment process once he has a chance to review the somewhat lengthy list of pending changes.

Comment: Glad to know it isn't just me who is frustrated with this. :)

Comment: 8 years later and this is still an issue for me. Better wait one more decade then.

Answer (score 8):

Tell me about it. In the meantime, you can use a heartbeat bookmarklet to ping the server:

```
javascript:void(setInterval(function foo(){with(new XMLHttpRequest)   {   open("POST",{},true);   setRequestHeader("Foo", "Bar");   send(""); foo = function(){}}},100000))
```

as a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't apply to the current [SEDE Logout issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313605/370758).