# Staying logged in when using SEDE on multiple machines

Tags: bug, data-explorer, auto-login

I am having problems staying logged into SEDE if I move between machines.

My work flow:

- Login to SEDE using Stack Exchange OpenID on laptop
- Run a few queries
- Move to desktop and log in to SEDE
- Run a few queries
- Move back to laptop and be required to log back in

This entire work flow can take place in a span of minutes, so I don't think it's related to a [timeout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182256/extend-or-remove-dataexplorer-timeout).

If I do all of my work on one machine, leave for a period of time and return to the same machine, I remain logged in.

I do not have this problem on any other SE sites.

Comment: Can you try with a Google account?

Comment: @rene I don't have a Google account linked to any of my SE accounts. Will that matter, or are you just asking if I can replicate it using Google as my sign on vs. Stack exchange?

Comment: I asked to see if you could replicate with a Google account but maybe it is better to wait till Oded (or another dev responds).

Comment: @rene - I am using a Google account. And using it is even more painful. There is no option to stay logged in. I.e. once I close the window I have to re-log in. I haven't tried with multiple machines. And we need to wait for [Tim Stone's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone) reply.