# Can we have the new Captcha on the Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, captcha

The new Captcha is active on the sites:

[image]

But on the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) we have the old one:

[image]

Could we have the new one on this as well please? Or is there a reason (less secure, doesn't work because of small amount of time spent on page) that we can't use that?

Comment: Hmm, probably. I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks :) It would be fine, except I don't stay logged in :/

Comment: @Tim yes by the way, why data.se throws me away every day? I finally got tired to log in every day and use capcha instead...

Comment: @nicael See [Extend or Remove DataExplorer timeout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182256), I'll see if I can get an update on that.